# journalctl is full of "audit" messages but there is no auditd

Tags: systemd-journald

I have several 18.04 servers which began life as 14.04 machines. Most (not all interestingly) have their `journalctl` logs full of "audit" messages. `auditd` is not installed. There is a `libaudit1` and a `libaudit-common` installed but my Google searches give me no traction.

Where are they coming from and how do I get rid of them (there are so many the log is basically choked)?

EDIT:

examples:

```
Apr 02 10:11:15 netnagios audit[1676]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=56 success=yes exit=29962 a0=1200011 a1=0 a2=0 a3=7f4375585a10 items=0 ppid=1675 pid=1676 auid=1003 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts2 ses=1 comm="bash" exe="/bin/bash" key=(null)                                    
Apr 02 10:11:15 netnagios audit: PROCTITLE proctitle="/bin/bash"                                        
Apr 02 10:11:15 netnagios audit[29962]: SYSCALL arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=55c66d887060 a1=55c66db57340 a2=55c66db7b200 a3=8 items=2 ppid=1676 pid=29962 auid=1003 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts2 ses=1 comm="journalctl" exe="/bin/journalctl" key=(null)          
Apr 02 10:11:15 netnagios audit: EXECVE argc=2 a0="journalctl" a1="-xe"                                 
Apr 02 10:11:15 netnagios audit: CWD cwd="/usr/local/nagios"                                            
Apr 02 10:11:15 netnagios audit: PATH item=0 name="/bin/journalctl" inode=201760 dev=08:01 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
```

Comment: Are these "APPARMOR" logs? You'll see `AVC apparmor` in the line. `Edit` your question and paste one of the lines into your question.

Comment: Solved it.
Security team had us install FireEye xagt and it's generating the noise.

Answer (score 1):

`auditd` itself became optional, [`journald`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-journald.8.html) provides the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try `systemctl status <nnn>` and replace `nnn` with one of the process IDs you found in your output (1676 or 29962 in your example). This reveals the service the program being logged belongs to and may help to find its configuration files to be changed.

Comment: (see my comment above) xagt is  a security tool from FireEye (presumably they simply took the auditd code and tweaked it since it still says "audit" in the log).